# Can ${e^{ikx}}$ and the heaviside step funtion have similar physics content about the distribution of $x$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematics

in an [online video lecture,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVIlit-PpN8&list=PLNs8zPL1U25HTt3ZDKdqLj0CVOCmAmKXn&index=33&t=0s)(around 38min, where the exactly statement is at 38min28secs.)
i got one question,
suppose we have a system of $N$ particles, $\left\{ {{{\vec r}_i}(t)} \right\}i = 1, \cdot  \cdot  \cdot ,N$ are the position vectors of the particles. 
I was told in the lecture that the so-called self intermediate scattering function is defined as.
$${F_s}(k,t) = \frac{1}{N}\left\langle {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{e^{i\vec k \cdot [{{\vec r}_i}(t) - {{\vec r}_i}(0)]}}} } \right\rangle.$$ (for homogeneous system, it only depends on the absolute value of $\vec k$.)

Furthrmore, also defined is the overlap funtion 
$${Q_s} = \frac{1}{N}\left\langle {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\theta (a - \left| {{{\vec r}_i}(t) - {{\vec r}_i}(0)} \right|)} } \right\rangle.$$
where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function and $a$ is a scaler at constant value

it is said that ${F_s}(k,t)$ and ${Q_s}$ are equivalent and have similar physical content if $2\pi/k$ is replaced by $a$. But I really did not see why. Could anybody give me some help on it. Thanks!

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/506279/2451

Comment: Note that you missplaced the averaging in the first expression. Don't know the answer but it may help to look at integral representations of the Heaviside function.